# tkinter GUI quiz that uses buttons for answers

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a quiz in python tkinter  and when the user click on the answers if the answer is wrong the correct answer text color is changed to green I got that working but when I add the disable function so the user can't answer the question again it's not showing the correct answer in green.

```
def check(self, guess):
    #compares the guess to the correct answer
    print ("guess " + guess)
    correct = self.problems[self.counter].correct
    print ("correct " + correct)
    self.btnA.config(state='disabled')
    self.btnB.config(state='disabled')
    self.btnC.config(state='disabled')
    self.btnD.config(state='disabled')
    if guess == correct:
      #update ans
      if guess == "A":
         self.astatus["text"] = "✓"
      elif guess == "B":
         self.bstatus["text"] = "✓"
      elif guess == "C":
         self.cstatus["text"] = "✓" 
      else:
         self.dstatus["text"] = "✓"
      self.marks+=10

    else:
      if guess == "A":
         self.astatus["text"] = "x"
      elif guess == "B":
         self.bstatus["text"] = "x"
      elif guess == "C": 
         self.cstatus["text"] = "x"
      else:
         self.dstatus["text"] = "x"


      if correct == "A":
         self.btnA["fg"] = 'green'
      elif correct == "B":
         self.btnB["fg"] = 'green'
      elif correct == "C": 
         self.btnC["fg"] = 'green'
      else:
         self.btnD["fg"] = 'green'
```

Comment: You need to include enough code to reproduce the problem, but no more than necessary. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: FWIW, when you disable a `Button` it becomes grayed-out to indicate its state—which is likely overriding whatever color was previously assigned to the text.

Comment: That said, `Button`s also have a separate `disabledforeground` option that determines what its color is when disabled.